# How to save millions of rows in MySQL in table with structure of two column?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, query-optimization, database-performance

I have around 600 millions of record in a format of Text and CSV File, I would like to keep these in MySQL for filtering. The file only contains information with two columns; one for SKU and another for Unique ID to identify.

So my question is, how can I design a table structure to get faster response on shared hosting environment?

Answer (score 2):

600 million rows in a shared hosting environment! Any hosting company that sees you doing any slightly complicated query on a data set of that size is bound to red-flag your account. Depending on the size of the data, I'd suggest getting your own SSD VM, or a large dedicated machine. If it's a short-term requirement, I'd even suggest a high end memory intensive EC2 instance.

With regards to structure, there's very little you can do with such a small number of columns, apart from correctly indexing your data. Can you provide a few example rows of data?

With a data set of that size, you may even want to look at using a distributed solution, like MongoDB, so that queries can be off-loaded onto multiple high performance servers (again, SSD VM?).

Comment: THanks Mate, What if I go with EC2 & VM? Do I need to update my.cnf there.

Comment: EC2 will basically be a new Linux (or Windows, depending on the image you choose) machine. You'd need to update your my.cnf file with whatever custom changes (i.e. memory usage) you desire. Amazon also provide a service called RDS, which is basically a pre-configured MySQL instance. You might find this to be cheaper than an EC2 instance, easier to setup, and come pre-configured for a high memory usage scenario, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: For example, an RDS db.r3.2xlarge instance (64gb ram) instance will cost $0.945 per hour. You could hook a small EC2 instance on to that as a database connection, to provide the PHP interface.